# Jquery slideshow image caption

Tags: jquery, slideshow, jquery-cycle, caption

I am trying to make the text of a paragraph equal to the alt tag of an image I am using this code and the cycle plugin for jquery.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">.slideshow{height:770px;width:365px;margin:auto}.slideshow    img{padding:10px;border:1px solid #ccc;background-color:#000000}</style>
<!-- include jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- include Cycle plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){
///Added ready function to ensure code works on slower browsers
$(document).ready(function(){$('.slideshow').cycle({fx:'fade', pause: 1});});
    $("#test1").text(("#slideshow2").attr("alt"));
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slideshow2" class="slideshow">
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg"  width="365" height="770" alt="1"/>
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach2.jpg" width="365" height="770" alt="2"/>
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach3.jpg" width="365" height="770" alt="3"/>
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach4.jpg" width="365" height="770" alt="4"/>
    <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach5.jpg" width="365" height="770" alt="5"/>
</div>
<p id=test1></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you and sorry in advance for what I am assuming is a fairly stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx:'fade', 
        pause: 1,
        after: function() {
           var altText = $('#slideshow2').find('img:visible').attr('alt');
           $('#test1').text(altText);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much I hate to ask for more, but could you explain why that works? And what was wrong about mine? I would like to get better not just use other people.

Comment: Firstly you had a typo, you forgot to put a "$" before ("#slideshow2"), secondly, the part you try to take alt attr is wrong, you should take it from the image, not from the image holder. But even if you did does things right it wouldn't have worked again. You were trying to get the alt attr only once, but you need to do it after each new slide, that is where the callback "after" comes in the game. So after each slide we take the current visible element alt atribute and add it to #test1 div.